# Event not getting captured in ng-change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);


app.controller('OrderFormController', function($scope, $http, $filter, $window, $location) {

$scope.names = ['test','test2'];

$scope.retrieveSelectedClass = function(newValue, oldValue, $event) {

alert($event);
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">

<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="OrderFormController">
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-click="event = $event" ng-change="retrieveSelectedClass(selectedName, '{{selectedName}}', event)"
                ng-options="(item.name||item) group by item.groupName for item in names"
                class="code-helper" id="code-helperId">
            <option value="">Select Option</option>
        </select>
        </body>
</html>
```

I have read that event does not gets captured in ng-change.

So I changed my select to :

```
    <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-click="event = $event" ng-change="retrieveSelectedClass(selectedName, '{{selectedName}}', event)"
            ng-options="(item.name||item) group by item.groupName for item in names"
            class="code-helper" id="code-helperId">
        <option value="">Select Option</option>
    </select>
```

And my js to :

```
$scope.retrieveSelectedClass = function(newValue, oldValue, $event) {

}
```

but still the event is undefined.

I have used this to detect ctrl key pressed :

```
$scope.retrieveSelectedClass = function(newValue, oldValue, $event) {
var windowsEvent = $window;

if (windowsEvent.event.ctrlKey) {
        windowsEvent.open('/html/apexEditor.html?name=' + newValue.name, '_blank');
        $scope.selectedName = possibleOldValues[0];
        return;
    }
    }
```

but this fails in firefox as there is no $windows.event in firefox.
I need to detect ctrl key and open in new tab. 
I cannot do ann onkeyup or onkeydown as that event will always gets listened unnecessarily. 
Can anybody help here?

Comment: Can you provide runnable code snippet of your code? That would be easy and faster to debug

Comment: @VicJordan I have added a snippet in the question.

Answer (score 0):

try `ng-change="retrieveSelectedClass(selectedName, '{{selectedName}}', $event)"` instant of `ng-change="retrieveSelectedClass(selectedName, '{{selectedName}}', event)"`

and in js

`$scope.retrieveSelectedClass = function(newValue, oldValue, event) {
}`

Answer (score 0):

You **can not pass event** to `ng-change`.

ng-change is not a directive for handling the change event (I realize that this is confusing given the name), but is actually instead notified when ngModelController.$setViewValue() is called and the value changes (because ng-change adds a listener to the $viewChangeListeners collection). So this is as expected.

Reference [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6370).

**Workaround:**

Please have a look at this [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/lmObXQzxRNlFeYoSYRIH?p=preview).

Comment: I have already listened to changed values , but how to listen to ctrl key pressed. I am not trying to listen to change via event.

Comment: @NagendraSingh when user is pressing `ctrl key`?

Comment: Yes. When user presses ctrl key then I need to open a new tab, as already posted in my question, windows event works only in chrome, but cross browser compatibility fails when I use windows event.

Answer (score 0):

remove the (click) event and try this

```js
$scope.retrieveSelectedClass = function(newValue, $event) {

  alert($event);
  }
});
```

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="OrderFormController">
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-change="retrieveSelectedClass(selectedName, $event)"
                ng-options="(item.name||item) group by item.groupName for item in names"
                class="code-helper" id="code-helperId">
            <option value="">Select Option</option>
        </select>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This would never work as ng-change can never detect $event.

`ngMouse, ng-change does not provide an event object.`